# Unity3D locking configurable joint

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do you lock configurable joint in Unity3D in new position?

When I set new position with Target Rotation, and then set Angular YMotion to Locked, it returns to it's original (not rotated) state and locks there. How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

If the "Locked" state does not work for you. My guess is that you could try and use the LateUpdate function to achieve what you want.

```
// LateUpdate is called after all Update functions have been called.
// This will ensure that your joint will always have the same rotation, even after the physics have been into play.
void LateUpdate() {
    // Set the target Rotation
}
```